# Trouble getting VSCode to honor tab size

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prettier

I'm starting up with NextJS, React, and TailwindCSS. I have the Prettier extension installed on VSCode, as well as in my project. In my VS Code Settings, I see `Tab Size` is set to 4, but it says it's being modified somewhere else. The only other place I can see it being affected is

```
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.indentSize": "tabSize",
```

But when I go into a file and hit tab, I get two spaces. On the bottom bar, I see it set to `Spaces: 2`. I can't figure out where the 2 setting is coming from or overriding the 4 setting.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I added it to the workspace settings, and looks good now.